# How to interpolate for points between two points on a coordinate?

Tags: interpolation

I have several known points from 0 to 180 on a polar graph. I could just have straight lines between each point and this approximation might be OK but I was hoping to achieve a better approximation.

If I know several points between 0 - 180 on a graph how best should I be interpolating unknown points at a given angle?

Answer (score 0):

Having some values `F(theta1), F(theta2).. F(thetan)` you can build some approximation (if exact coincidence is not required) or interpolation function `F(theta)`. It is the same process as interpolation of `Y(X)` for cartesian coordinates.

Depending on point distribution, function might be rather simple like quadratic  or cubic polynomial. If approximation differs from points positions too much, look at [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) (polynomial power coincides with point number).

Perhaps you may want to calculate some spline interpolation (set of functions for every interval between points. There is a lot of spline kinds).

Comment: I was thinking pretty much the same thing, however, a wrinkle is that curves mapped out in polar coordinates are going to be somewhat different than the nominally-same curves in rectangular coordinates. For example, straight lines turn into, I guess, circular arcs. The effect is probably more pronounced the closer one gets to the origin. Whether that's acceptable or desirable, maybe it is, I don't know; wouldn't hurt to just try it and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem. I thought about building a sequence of points against theta angle, but you perhaps talk about curves suitable for drawing. In this case I'd suggest Bezier curves. We already have endpoints, and need to calculate control points for nice interpolation.

Comment: @MBo should I use the linear bezier curve formula between two known points with the difference between the known angles and the unknown point's angle as the %?

Comment: @bcardarella Could you show a picture of your point set? For some point arrangements it is quite easy to fit curve with Beziers, while some cases are harder

Comment: @bcardarella If you know angles at your points, problem is simpler a bit - we had to adapt only lengths of control "legs"